Does Boost guarantee safety of deserealization?
For example, a client serializes std::vector, std::unordered_map, boost::optional, std::shared_ptr or some other type whose serialization mechanism is laid out directly in Boost, and then sends it to the server. The server receives this packet and deserializes it, catching boost::archive::archive_exception if necessary and discarding the packet.
Does this approach guarantee that the server won't crash with some SIGSEGV at the moment of deserialization attempt (inside the try block) or when working with deserialized structures afterwards, even if a person on the client tries very hard?c++

Boost deserialization can crash your program with minimal effort on attacker's part. Take any XML archive, find any class_id_reference= attribute, and change the value to anything that is not in the archive. Deserialization will crash. But this is at least something Boost can theoretically fix. There are things Boost cannot fix even in theory.
All but the simplest data structures have implicit invariants that Boost knows nothing about and does not enforce. If an attacker crafts an archive where one of those invariants are violated, and your program does not explicitly checks them on deserialization, it's game over.
Say, your data structure is a tree. You build it as a tree and maintain it as a tree. Is what you have just deserialized indeed a tree? You need to check, because Boost can give you an arbitrary graph. Have two separate trees? Perhaps you want to make sure no node of one tree occurs in the other one. What if you have a whole bunch of trees?
Or suppose data structure contains several standard containers, and several iterators that point within these containers. You know which iterator points to each container. That's your invariant — you create iterators in a certain way, and do not change their affiliation.  Or perhaps you have pairs of iterators such that the elements of the pair must point to the same container. Your program implicitly assumes that these invariants hold. But it is trivial for an attacker to craft an archive that violates them. And there is no good way checking them since there is no way to get a container from an iterator. In order to verify that two iterators point inside the same container, you generally need to iterate every container of that type that your program serializes. And for the next pair of iterators, do it all over again.
Same thing is true about plain old pointers that point to array elements.

That is to say: boost can guarantee everything related to the transport protocol and data encoding, but it cannot guarantee any invariants that are needed by higher levels of the program logic. Right?

@j6t boost can in principle guarantee everything related to the transport protocol and data encoding, but doesn't necessarily do because of bugs/unimplemented features/whatever. But of course no guarantees for any high level invariants.
